# How to check if current user is member of the current site or above member group, site owner group etc

Tags: 2013, groups, user-controls

How can I do a check that looks if current user is a member group or above member group on current site?

Above member group I mean site owner group etc..

So far I have done:

```
var currentSite = SPContext.Current.Site;
var currentUser = SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.LoginName;
```

Any kind of help is appreciated

Comment: I can give you a javascript which checks the groupID the current user is in. Or has it to be c#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [SPWeb.DoesUserHavePermissions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.doesuserhavepermissions.aspx) method together with the [SPBasePermissions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spbasepermissions.aspx) enumeration.

Eg:

```
bool isUserOwner = SPContext.Current.Web.DoesUserHavePermissions(SPBasePermissions.ManageWeb);
```

This method will return true if the current user has the permission specified in the parameter. Have a look at the permissions enumeration to determine which is the best permission for your scenario.

Answer (score 1):

The following code demonstrates how to verify if the current user is in a particular role or has been assigned a specific permission level.

The code sample uses **SPContext.Current** to get a reference to the current site, as such it must be rUn under the context of SharePoint (in a web part, or custom application page), to run the code in a console application or windows application you will need to change how the reference to the SPWeb object is obtained

```
SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web; 

//**************************************** 
// Get a reference the roles that are 
// bound to the current user and the role 
// definition to which we need to verify 
// the user against 
SPRoleDefinitionBindingCollection usersRoles = web.AllRolesForCurrentUser; 
SPRoleDefinitionCollection roleDefinitions = web.RoleDefinitions; 
SPRoleDefinition roleDefinition = roleDefinitions["Full Control"]; 

// Check if the user is in the role. If not 
// redirect the user to the access denied page 
if (usersRoles.Contains(roleDefinition)) 
{ 
   //******************************* 
   //Check if post back to run 
   //code that initiates the page 
   if (IsPostBack != true) 
   { 
    //Do your stuff here 
   } 
} 
else 
{ 
    Response.Redirect(“/_layouts/accessdenied.aspx”); 
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to do it in way that it checks Contribute and above permissions? I dont like it to be hardcoded values